# Python Requests OAuth2 header with access token

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, python-requests

I am trying to use Python requests to use the API of Adform. How do I exactly include the access token (which I could successfully retrieve already) in my get request header?

I understand the API is based on OAuth2, and I am trying to use Client Credentials authorization. Here is the API docs: http://api.adform.com/help/guides/authorization-guide#consumingapis
I really can't tell the exact format of my header from this small amount of information.
I've tried:

```
requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'MY_TOKEN_HERE'}
requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer MY_TOKEN_HERE'}
requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'access_token MY_TOKEN_HERE'}
```

None works unfortunately, all return <401> unauthorized. My access token is valid for sure.

Comment: `requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer MY_TOKEN_HERE'})` should be correct, what endpoint are u using?

Comment: Is it possible that there is a difference between:
`token = MY_TOKEN_HERE`
`headers={'Authorization':'Bearer ' + token}`
and
`headers={'Authorization':'Bearer MY_TOKEN_HERE'}`

For some reason the first works for me but the second doesn't. I found it out by accident after your reply, I was using the second one before

Comment: Can you please post the full code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

`requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer MY_TOKEN_HERE'}` should work, as long as `MY_TOKEN_HERE` is valid.

You may use [`requests_oauth2client`](https://github.com/guillp/requests_oauth2client) to format the header properly with an AuthHandler:

```
from requests_oauth2client import BearerAuth

requests.get(url, auth=BearerAuth("MY_TOKEN_HERE"))
```

And you may even use it to get the access token easily, and have a requests Session that will automatically get the token as required and cache it as long as it is valid from next API calls:

```
from requests_oauth2client import OAuth2Client, OAuth2ClientCredentialsAuth
import requests

# define your OAuth2 client, with a Token Endpoint URL, a Client ID and a secret.
client = OAuth2Client("https://url.to.the.token.endpoint", auth=("CLIENT_ID", "CLIENT_SECRET"))

# use a session to benefit from token caching
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = OAuth2ClientCredentialsAuth(client, scope="YOUR_SCOPE"))

resp = session.get(url) # an access token will be obtained as required at this point before the API call is done
```

Answer (score -2):

this one

> curl --location --request GET
>   'https://api.adform.com/v1/seller/publishers' \
>   --header 'Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN_HERE'

Comment: Hello there, OP required use of Python, not cURL.